# Running grails 2.2.4 on grails 2.5.1

Tags: grails

i have Grails project developed with **Grails2.2.4** , and the grails installed on my machine is **Grails 2.5.1** , how i could run this project on my current Grails version ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are able to modify the project itself, you can change the `app.grails.version` property within the `application.properties` file.

It should be `app.grails.version=2.2.4`, set it accordingly.

You may run into issues with the newer version of grails (beyond the scope of this question), follow this link to help resolve them:  http://grails.github.io/grails-doc/2.5.x/guide/upgradingFrom22.html

Comment: thanks , but is this the only way to make it working

Answer (score 0):

Not clear from your question, but do you want to RUN the 2.2.4 grails project on your machine, or UPGRADE the 2.2.4 project to 2.5.1?

If simply running the 2.2.4 project, I'd load gvm (now SDKMAN, google it) as the tool of choice for installing and switching grails versions, groovy versions, etc.

The *nix version works great, but I have no experience with the Powershell CLI version for Windows.

Comment: i want to run project developed with Grails 2.2.4 on Grails 2.5.1 without upgrading.

Comment: Well, that might or might not work, depends on the application. You would need to read through the changelogs for each of the version steps to see if a change from grails 2.2.4 ->  2.5.1 breaks something. I know at work, we got bit with a change in the GORM layer when going from 2.2.something to 2.4.3. There are something like 20 Grails version releases between your 2.2.4 and 2.5.1 versions, so I would not bet on it working right out of the box.

Comment: after a lot of trying ,errors fixing and debugging  , i found the easiest way to run it is to download  Grails 2.2.4 and run it on it, it worked perfectly .